# COUNT no firebase

Tags: android, firebase, count

Olá,

Há a possibilidade de fazer COUNT (contagem dos registros) no firebae database?
Porque gostaria de retornar em meu app o total de ocorrências criadas(TODAS de todos os usuários) e total por usuário, mas, não sei como faço para realizar o count no banco do firebase.

O count que queria fazer é para o banco abaixo.
[image: Database firebase]

Alguém consegue me ajudar?
Abraços.

Answer (score 1):

Segue abaixo um exemplo de código para fazer essa contagem por posto e total:

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("usuario");

ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        int mTotal=0;

        for (DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String mUserKey = snap.getKey();
            if (snap.child("ocorrencia").exists()) {
                map.put(mUserKey, (int) snap.child("ocorrencia").getChildrenCount());
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.printf("%s -> %s%n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            mTotal = mTotal + entry.getValue();
        }
        System.out.printf("Somatória total de ocorrências: %s%n", mTotal);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```